# Converting "application's" memory address

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, memory, reverse-engineering

So I am writing my very first trainer for Microsoft's Spider Solitaire. First I needed to backwards-engineer all memory adresses until I found a static one. I used offsets so I can easily revert them back.

I've found this:

```
1000157F78  <-- starting value(never changes)
+ E8        <-- offsets to pointers
+ 14
002DC3D4    <-- final adress(changes every time)
```

This is how my trainer gets his final memory address:

```
DWORD FindFinalAddr(HANDLE hProc, BYTE offsets[], DWORD baseAddress, unsigned char pointerLevel)
{
    DWORD pointer = baseAddress;
    DWORD pTemp = 0;
    DWORD pointerAddr = 0;

    // set base address
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)pointer, &pTemp, (DWORD)sizeof(pTemp), NULL);

    for (int c = 0; c < pointerLevel; c++)
    {
        pointerAddr = pTemp + (DWORD)offsets[c];
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)pointerAddr, &pTemp, (DWORD)sizeof(pTemp), NULL);
    }

    return pointerAddr;
}
```

In this case, I do(roughly) this: `FindFinalAddr(hProc, {0xE8, 0x14}, 0x1000157F78, 2);`

This works fine when Spider Solitaire is open and I have just found the static value.
But when I close it and re-open it's no longer valid.

I found out that `1000157F78` is actually `SpiderSolitaire.exe+B5F78` It's like a offset. If I enter this in cheat engine I get the right memory address, but I can't just simply enter it in my code.

Now is my question: How do I convert `SpiderSolitaire.exe+B5F78` to the right memory adress?

Note: SpiderSolitaire.exe is 64 bit.

**EDIT:**
I've tried the following:

```
void * entryPoint = (void*) hProc;

DWORD base_addr = ((DWORD)(entryPoint) + 0xB5F78);
```

But that doesn't work, because the entry point is `5C`. The adress it should give(in this session) is `FF7A5F78`, but what really happens is `5C + B5F78 = B5F4D`.

Comment: Address Space Randomization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: This is system specific. You don't state the system (other than some M$ system). Version? 64-bit? 32-bit?

Comment: Good point, @user3344003. I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @user: This is **not** system specific. The API calls required to determine the base address of a module are available for all supported versions of Windows, and they are used identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long period of research I've found my own answer!
This piece of code gets the module base address(AKA entry point)(you need to include TlHelp32.h and tchar.h):

```
DWORD getModuleBaseAddr(DWORD procId, TCHAR * lpszModuleName)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, procId);
    DWORD moduleBaseAddr = 0;

    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 mentry32 = { 0 };
        mentry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &mentry32))
        {
            do
            {
                if (_tcscmp(mentry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    moduleBaseAddr = (DWORD)mentry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &mentry32));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error on finding module base address: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }

    return moduleBaseAddr;
}
```

You give it the pid and the name of the module(like game.exe), then it browses through modules and check if they are the same, and then it returns the base address.

Now, I tested this with Spider Solitaire. It gave me an error.
That is because my compiled code was 32 bit and SpiderSolitaire.exe was 64 bit, which was caused because my Windows 7 was 64 bit.

So make sure your code has the same platform target as the code you're aiming for!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can query the load address using [GetModuleInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201.aspx), passing `NULL` for the module handle parameter. If that doesn't work, you can take the longer route through [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631.aspx) and [GetModuleBaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196.aspx).

Comment: Yep, this is the way I've done similar things in the past. Alternatively you can inject code that then loads a DLL of your design, that DLL will be loaded in the process address space iteself, which makes it easier working with GetProcAddress.

Comment: I studied it, but I didn't really understand it. I tried, however. It didn't work, at least for the GetModuleInformation.
Can you give an example? Or what do I need to do with the ModuleInformation?

Comment: The module information contains the base address for the module to which your relative offsets should be added.

Comment: @Jester I tried this, I get different entry points(that's good), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the base address isn't exactly the same reference point, but it should just be a constant offset that you can easily calculate.

Comment: @Jester How calculate?